# Getting Items that was purchase along with certain categories and excluding unwanted categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, One is my Master Menu table and other is my order table. I want to get all orders that was purchased based on a category set by me from Master Menu table and exclude those orders that was purchased with certain categories. for example:

**Master Menu Table**

```
ItemCode       Category
-------------------------
10001         VM1
10002         VM1
10003         VM2
10004         VM3
10005         VM3
10006         HOT DRINKS
10007         HOT DRINKS
10008         COLD DRINKS
10009         COLD DRINKS
10066         DESSERT
```

**Order Table is:**

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemCode  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        06/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             16       10006    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Ice Tea       2             7        10008    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1

4        06/08/2018     Donuts        7             17       10066    122-7

1        06/08/2018     Bread         1             7        10003    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4

2        06/08/2018     OrangeJuice   2             5        10009    122-2
2        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10006    122-2

3        06/08/2018     Bread         3             5        10003    122-3
3        06/08/2018     Beans         7             17       10004    122-3
3        06/08/2018     Coffee        17            17       10006    122-3

3        06/08/2018     Ice Tea       7             17       10008    122-5

4        06/08/2018     OrangeJuice   7             17       10009    122-6
```

**Result:**

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemCode  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
4        06/08/2018     Donuts        7             17       10066    122-7

2        06/08/2018     OrangeJuice   2             5        10009    122-2
2        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10006    122-2

3        06/08/2018     Ice Tea       7             17       10008    122-5

4        06/08/2018     OrangeJuice   7             17       10009    122-6
```

**Expected Result**:

I want to get all orders details that was purchased with category set in (HOT DRINKS,COLD DRINKS,DESSERT) and exclude those OrderNo's with category set in (VM1,VM2,VM3). keeping in mind if an order contains both, the entire OrderNo should not appear in my output query. for instance: I should not get OrderNo:122-3 as it contains an ItemCodes that are present in my Master Item Table Category (VM2,VM3,HOT DRINKS).

Comment: Good job, but your question miss something important, which is _the expected results as formatted text_ as it's the clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `group by` and `having` solve this problem:

```
select o.orderno
from orders o join
     mastermenu mm
     on o.itemcode = mm.itemcode
group by o.orderno
having sum(case when mm.category in ('HOT DRINKS', 'COLD DRINKS', 'DESSERT') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when mm.category in ('VM1', 'VM2', 'VM3') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `sum(case . . . )` count the number of matching items for those categories.  The `> 0` says that at least one is in the order.  The `= 0` says none are in the order.

EDIT:

Is this what you want?

```
with om as (
      select o.*, mm.category
      from orders o join
           mastermenu mm
           on o.itemcode = mm.itemcode
     )
select om.*
from om
where om.category in ('HOT DRINKS', 'COLD DRINKS', 'DESSERT') and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from om om2
                  where om2.orderno = om.orderno and 
                        om2.category in ('VM1', 'VM2', 'VM3')
                 );
```

Comment: this query will remove those unwanted items within my order, whereas I don't want to get the entire order itself

Comment: @3MRAN Well, as I mention before, better to include the expected results as formatted text, same as the results you post in yoour question, so please edit your question and add the expected results, this is the best explanation to get better answers :)

Comment: @Sami Thanks for your input. I have edited the same now :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
     Create Table #MasterMenu(itemCode Bigint,Category Varchar(50))

     Insert into #MasterMenu
    SElect 10001,'VM1' Union All
    SElect 10002,'VM1' Union All
    SElect 10003,'VM2' Union All
    SElect 10004,'VM3' Union All
    SElect 10005,'VM3' Union All
    SElect 10006,'HOT DRINKS' Union All
    SElect 10007,'HOT DRINKS' Union All
    SElect 10008,'COLD DRINKS' Union All
    SElect 10009,'COLD DRINKS' Union All
    SElect 10066,'DESSERT'


    Create Table #Order(SiteId int, BusinessDate Date,ItemName Varchar(50), UnitsSold int,UnitsSale int,ItemCode Bigint , OrderNo Varchar(50))

    Insert Into #Order
    SELECT 1,'06/08/2018','Apple  ',1 ,5 ,10001,'122-1' Union All
    SELECT 1,'06/08/2018','Coffee ',1 ,16,10006,'122-1' Union All
    SELECT 1,'06/08/2018','Ice Tea',2 ,7 ,10008,'122-1' Union All
    SELECT 1,'06/08/2018','Beans  ',9 ,18,10004,'122-1' Union All
    SELECT 4,'06/08/2018','Donuts ',7 ,17,10066,'122-7' Union All
    SELECT 1,'06/08/2018','Bread  ',1 ,7 ,10003,'122-4' Union All
    SELECT 1,'06/08/2018','Beans  ',4 ,8 ,10004,'122-4' Union All
    SELECT 2,'06/08/2018','OrangeJuice',2 ,5 ,10009,'122-2' Union All
    SELECT 2,'06/08/2018','Coffee ',1 ,6 ,10006,'122-2' Union All
    SELECT 3,'06/08/2018','Bread  ',3 ,5 ,10003,'122-3' Union All
    SELECT 3,'06/08/2018','Beans  ',7 ,17,10004,'122-3' Union All
    SELECT 3,'06/08/2018','Coffee ',17,17,10006,'122-3' Union All
    SELECT 3,'06/08/2018','Ice Tea',7 ,17,10008,'122-5' Union All
    SELECT 4,'06/08/2018','OrangeJuice',7 ,17,10009,'122-6' 

    ;with cte
    As
    (
        Select OrderNo,SUM(CASE WHEN ItemCode in (10001,10002,10003) then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ItemCount
        from #Order
        Group by OrderNo
    )

    Select o.* from cte c
    INNER JOIN #Order o on c.OrderNo=o.OrderNo
    Where c.ItemCount=0


    Drop Table #MasterMenu
    Drop Table #Order
```

output:

```
SiteId  BusinessDate    ItemName    UnitsSold   UnitsSale   ItemCode    OrderNo
  2      2018-06-08     OrangeJuice    2            5         10009      122-2
  2      2018-06-08     Coffee         1            6         10006      122-2
  3      2018-06-08     Ice Tea        7            17        10008      122-5
  4      2018-06-08     OrangeJuice    7            17        10009      122-6
  4      2018-06-08     Donuts         7            17        10066      122-7
```